# Elasticsearch (Elasticsearch Curator) Python API. Get dictionary of ES indices and their sizes

Tags: python, api, dictionary, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I can get all of ES indexes in list via such code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

indices=es.indices.get_aliases().keys()
sorted(indices)
```

But is it possible to get dictionary like `{'index1': '100gb', 'index2': '10gb', 'index3': '15gb'}`. So i mean dic with index name and size of them.

Comment: Which version of the API are you using?  Curator 4 does this as part of the IndexList initialization.

Comment: The reason I ask is it appears that you are not using Curator at all here, even though you list Elasticsearch Curator in the title and as a tag.  The below answer is appropriate, but still does not use Curator.  Was the Curator tag in error?

Comment: @untergeek Then I was ready to use curstor-python binding as option. But looks that it can't show me index size info.

Comment: You might be using an older version.  Curator 4, as noted, has this.  I'll provide another bit below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My variant:

```
import elasticsearch

client = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()
all_indices = client.indices.stats(metric='store', human=True)['indices'].keys()
dic_indices = {}

for index in all_indices:
    size = client.indices.stats(metric='store', human=True)['indices'][index]['total']['store']['size']
    dic_indices[index] = size

print dic_indices
```

Result has next view:

```
{u'haproxy-2016.09.02': u'1.6gb', u'haproxy-2016.09.03': u'827.3mb', u'marathon-2016.09.03': u'296.1mb', u'docker-2016-09-06': u'187.2mb', u'haproxy-2016.09.06': u'339.7mb', u'haproxy-2016.09.04': u'647.5mb', u'haproxy-2016.09.05': u'595.5mb'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Curator 4 pulls much of the index metadata at IndexList initialization.  It's in bytes, rather than in human readable sizes, if that matters.

It is in **IndexList.index_info[index_name]['size_in_bytes']**

Read more about the IndexList method at http://curator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/objectclasses.html#indexlist

```
import elasticsearch
import curator
client = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(host='127.0.0.1')

il = curator.IndexList(client)
print('{0}'.format(il.indices))
[u'topbeat-2016.09.01', ...]

print('{0}'.format(il.index_info['topbeat-2016.09.01'])
{'number_of_replicas': u'1', 'size_in_bytes': 706503044, 'number_of_shards': u'5', 'docs': 1629986, 'age': {'creation_date': 1472688002}, 'state': u'open', 'segments': 0}
```